# jsplumb create curved connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb, connector

I have a diagram with state machine connectors,

```
instance.connect(
                               {
                                   source: "estadoDg-1" ,
                                   target: "estadoDg-2" ,
                                   //connector: ["StateMachine", { proximityLimit: 0, curviness: -46 }]
                               });
```

As you can see in the image green connector is background of second element,
I want to curve connector like red line (ref)..

thanks

[image: jsplumb diagram]

Answer (score 4):

well
it's not optimal solution, but I get a approach of desire result

```
 instance.connect(
                               {
                                   source: "estadoDg-" + datos[i].idEtapa,
                                   target: "estadoDg-" + datos[j].idEtapa,
                                   connector: ["Bezier", { curviness: 30 }]                                   
                                   //connector: ["StateMachine", { proximityLimit: 0, curviness: -46 }]
                                   //connector: ["Flowchart", { minStubLength: 40 }]
                               });
```